# rust "hello world" causes 'mouse option' window to open. Why?

Tags: powershell, rust, windows-11

I am on windows 11
I executed rustup-init.exe

Create a `main.rs` file with

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I then executed `rustc main.rs` from Windows Power Shell to compile the program

Then, from Power Shell, i executed `main`

I got nothing at all on console. The prompt simply goes to new lines.
Then without any apparent reason, the following setting window of windows 11 will popup.

[image]

[image]

What damn is happening ?!?!

> This happens only from Power Shell
>
> From cmd it works
>
> [image]

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you are typing exactly, as you say you type `rustc main.rs`, but actually show that you are typing `main.rs`. Incidentally, `rustc main.rs` will not execute your program, just compile it. If you want a more user-friendly cli to compile and execute Rust programs, I would suggest using cargo.

Comment: You will get this if you enter `main.cpl` -- this is the Control Panel's "Main" item (or it used to be, way back in the WIndows 3.1 days, for compatibility purposes), and Windows knows how to "start" `.cpl` files. Getting it if you just enter `main` does seem unusual, but likely some variation on this. AFAICT this only works from PowerShell; `cmd` doesn't allow plain `main`.

Comment: @BlackBeans: sorry,  I fixed my question. I compiled then executed

Comment: Ah, there's the rest of the mystery -- on my machine, in PowerShell the `PATHEXT` environment variable includes `.CPL`, allowing those files to start without an extension, but not in `cmd`. If you actually have a `main.exe` in your directory, then PowerShell will start that too, but *only* if you do `.\main`, since (for security purposes) PowerShell will not run executables in the current directory. So your `main.exe` is out but the `main.cpl` in System32 is not, and that starts instead. A curious confluence of configuration confusion.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: you're right. Executing `main.exe` will execute my compiled software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As suggested from @JeroenMostert in the comment

Executing from Power Shell the command `main` will execute automatically the `.cpl`.

Indeed, executing `main.exe` will execute my executable.

Damn.